# Android: Two different layout includes in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bit of a long layout file which i want to restructure by pulling two chunks out of the layout file into independent layout files, and include them in the main layout file.

My problem is how to make `include2` come right underneath `include1` as in normal `RelativeLayout` behaviour. The `include` tag doesn't know `layout_above` and `layout_below`. A solution would be using a `LinearLayout` instead, but then the button attached to the bottom of the screen (in the main layout file) cannot hold its place any more.

Main layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.stats.weekly.WeeklyStatsFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include1"
            layout="@layout/weekly_stats_header_view" />

        <!-- Here I can't tell include2 to position itself under include1 -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/include2"
            layout="@layout/weekly_stats_content_view" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/statsButtonContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/statsButton"
                style="@style/StandardButtonGreen"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/material_horizontal_padding_half"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/material_horizontal_padding_half"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/material_horizontal_padding_half"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_horizontal_padding_half"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:text="@string/strWeeklyStatsActivityButtonText" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Solution update:**

As suggested by *Chirag* and *Dipali*, I added `layout_width` and `layout_height` so the `Layout_above` and `layout_below` become relevant:

```
...
<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/weekly_stats_content_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/weekly_stats_header_view"
    android:layout_above="@+id/statsButtonContainer"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like that with Relative Layout and if you want to use with Linear Layout then use weight :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/weekly_stats_header_view" />

    <!-- Here I can't tell include2 to position itself under include1 -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/weekly_stats_content_view" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/statsButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/statsButton"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Chirag, the `layout_below` won't work without also specifying `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the same include. Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Use your xml Just add `layout_width` and `layout_height` with `layout_below` property in `include2`.

```
    <include
                android:id="@+id/include2"
                layout_below = "@+id/include1"
                layout_width = "match_parent"
                layout_height = wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/weekly_stats_content_view" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use LinearLayout with includes and a button inside RelativeLayout.
Or 2 LinearLayouts - one with includes, another with button

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/demo1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/demo2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/statsButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

       <Button
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="Button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Whats the need for: `android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout"`?